# Optimizing JDBC query

Tags: mysql, optimization, jdbc

I've a program which connects to a DB and check for duplicate entries and deletes the duplicate and update the number of same text in the original record.

My problem is that with only 100000 record it is taking hours, and the program finishes with 'heapspace required' error.

How can I optimize this program to do the task pretty quick?

```
public class Main {
  // serveropsdb.properties file location = /opt/serverops/scripts/serverops.properties
  private final static String PROPERTIES_FILENAME=File.separatorChar+"opt"+File.separatorChar+"serverops"+File.separatorChar+"scripts"+File.separatorChar+"serveropsdb.properties";
  private final static String  DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_STARTTIME= "start.time";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_ENDTIME= "end.time";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_DB_TABLENAME= "db.tablename";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USERNAME= "db.username";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD= "db.password";
  private final static String  PROPERTY_NAME_DB_NAME= "db.name";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("DB consolidation started");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try { //loading serverops.properties file
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(PROPERTIES_FILENAME));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error loading "+PROPERTIES_FILENAME+" properties!");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try { // loading jdbc driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(" JDBC Driver not found");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver found! Connecting to Database");
    Connection connection = null;

    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    ResultSet findResultSet = null;

    PreparedStatement allStatement, findStatement, updateStatement;

    //date formate used yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
    DateTimeFormatter dateFromatter= DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

    DateTime startDate = dateFromatter.parseDateTime(properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_STARTTIME));
    DateTime endDate= dateFromatter.parseDateTime( properties.getProperty( PROPERTY_NAME_ENDTIME));

    Timestamp t1 = new Timestamp(startDate.getMillis());
    Timestamp t2 = new Timestamp(endDate.getMillis());

    StringBuilder sql;      
    String toBeRemovedIndex ;
    int updateNumEntries; 
    String toBeRemovedLog;
    String toBeRemovedHostname; 
    boolean  updateDB=false;

    try { // connecting to DB with credentials from the properties file 
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection( 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_NAME), 
        properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USERNAME),
        properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD));

  // getting all record between start time and end time 
      sql = new StringBuilder( "SELECT * FROM" 
                             + properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_TABLENAME)
                             + " WHERE last_seen BETWEEN ? AND ?");

      allStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
      allStatement.setTimestamp(1, t1);
      allStatement.setTimestamp(2,t2); 
      resultSet = allStatement.executeQuery( );

      while (resultSet.next()) {
        toBeRemovedIndex  = resultSet.getString(1);
        updateNumEntries = resultSet.getInt(2);
        toBeRemovedLog = resultSet.getString(3);
        toBeRemovedHostname = resultSet.getString(5);

        // selecting the duplicate entries with logmessage , id and hostname
        sql = new StringBuilder( "SELECT * FROM "
                               + properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_TABLENAME) 
                               + " where log_message=? and  id <> ? and hostname = ?"  );

        findStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        findStatement.setString(1, toBeRemovedLog );
        findStatement.setString(2, toBeRemovedIndex );
        findStatement.setString(3, toBeRemovedHostname);

        findResultSet  = findStatement.executeQuery();
        String newId="";
        while( findResultSet.next()) {
          newId = findResultSet.getString(1);
          updateNumEntries +=findResultSet.getInt(2);
          updateDB = true;
        }

        if(updateDB ) { //  if duplicate entry found - deleting it from the db 
          sql = new StringBuilder( "DELETE  FROM"
                                 + properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_TABLENAME)
                                 + " where id = ?" );
          updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
          updateStatement.setString(1, toBeRemovedIndex  );
          updateStatement.executeUpdate();

          // updating similar entry with number of records
          sql = new StringBuilder( "Update "
                                 + properties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_TABLENAME)
                                 + " set number_of_entries = ? where  id = ? " );

          updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
          updateStatement.setLong(1, updateNumEntries );
          updateStatement.setString(2, newId );
          updateStatement.executeUpdate();
          updateDB = false;
          updateStatement=null;
        }
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    DateTime now = new DateTime();

    if(connection != null) {
      try {
        connection.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    System.out.println( "Current time = "
                      + now.toString() 
                      + " DB consoladiation done successfully between "
                      + t1.toString() + " and "+ t2.toString());
    }
 }
```

Table structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `syslog_parsed` (
     `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `number_of_entries` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `log_message` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `hostname` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     KEY `ID` (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Try if it makes a difference if you `close` the statements and result sets when you no longer need them.

Comment: See my response below. Hopefully that heads you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you have nested while loops. Your inner loops perform sql queries on a table of 100k items. This means you have on the order of 100000^2 operations, including 100k sql calls. Further, none of your calls are closed, so Java keeps the resultant sets in memory - hence the heapsize error.

Much of your code is overkill, and can be elided with a sql statement. This may not be quite right, so you should test it against your database, but it gives you the key elements:

```
String sql = "SELECT id FROM ( "
           + "  SELECT id, log_message, hostname FROM syslog_parsed "
           + "  WHERE last_seen BETWEEN ? AND ? "
           + "  GROUP BY id, log_message, hostname "
           + ") x "//creates a subtable with grouped items
           + "GROUP BY id "
           + "HAVING count(*) > 1"//only returns rows that appear more than once

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
stmt.setTimestamp(1, t1);
stmt.setTimestamp(2, t2);
resultSet =  stmt.executeQuery( );

while (resultSet.next()) {
  //Copy result
  //Delete all of that result
  //Add back in one such result
}
```

This should run much faster, as the code will only have to deal with duplicates (no more than, presumably, 50k records, but probably much much less). It offloads the work of finding duplicates to sql, which is very good at this sort of task.

A note for the future: PLEASE format your code, otherwise it makes it hard to read. You might also want to try and focus what code actually matters.

Comment: thanks for the pointers - brain freeze I guess - It should've come to my mind - I thought it was for JDBC inappropriate programming 
:) 
I will try it out and let you know

Comment: Let me know if you run into a problem. And accept the answer if you don't! ;-)